# Issue installing FUSE 2.9.7 on Linux

Tags: linux, installation, raspberry-pi, fuse

I am Linux beginner and I am trying to install Fuse 2.9.7 on my Rasberry pi. I have Linux version 4.1.18. I have followed the tutorial on installing, after extracting the tarball and running ./configure I am unable to proceed with installation, because when I try to run ./make the command line says there is no such file. Any ideas how to fix this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must run make as a command

```
     make
```

not as a local program.

```
     ./make
```